# How to include properties via composition?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

After having to refactor the inheritance chain in my current project for the third time I googled "Inheritance sucks" and found that the problem I'm having is not uncommon and composition is a recommended alternative solution.

I understand how you can use composition to add behavior in form of functions, but I'm having problems to come up with ways to add properties by the same means.

Let's say I want to model tree nodes. Every node has at least two properties: name and description.

```
class Node {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Other more specific nodes would inherit those properties, like so:

```
class StructuredNode : Node {
   public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

How could I achieve similar re-usability of the property code without relying on inheritance and the problems that come with it?
Is there a design pattern for this or do I have to use inheritance in such a case?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Examples for the position "composition over inheritance":

- [ScottLilly](https://scottlilly.com/c-design-patterns-composition-over-inheritance/)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- [Codingdelight](https://codingdelight.com/2014/01/16/favor-composition-over-inheritance-part-1/)

Comment: Added an edit with pointers.

Comment: `public List<Node> Children;` is a field, not a property (just to be a little nitpicky)

Comment: Changed the definition.

Comment: _"similar re-usability of the property code without relying on inheritance"_ Decorator Pattern comes to my mind.

Comment: The decorator pattern seems also aimed mostly at methods and mainly be used if I need to make changes at run-time.

Comment: Yes, I just tried to come up with an example and it seems superfluent for properties ...

Answer (score 2):

Rather then depending on class , you should depend son abstraction (this also one part of making use of composition)  so for you case you should do like this

```
public interface INode {
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
}

class Node : INode {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

class StructuredNode : INode {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<INode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

or you can also do this

```
//this is something similar to decorator pattern.
class StructuredNode  {
   private readonly INode _node;
   public StructureNode(INode node)
   {
      _node = node;//now you can reuse function of any class which implements INode
   }

   public List<INode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

you should do like this also later on

```
   List<Node> nodes = List<Node>();
   StructuredNode sNode = new StructuredNode();
   sNode.Children  = nodes;
```

this is possible as all is based on abstraction. and all implementation now make use of `INode`

or

other solution suggested you in comment is make use of `Decorator pattern`. If you just want to extend you class without modifying it.

Comment: This solves the problem I have with the lack of readability of inheritance by repeating all code in all classes. I like that. 

But it does not solve the problem, that you have to refactor a lot, if you discover new cases.

For example I just found that I want to have nodes that are just used for structuring my view-model and therefore don't have a description.

Comment: @RubenBohnet - i suggest make use of constructor injection if you want to use other class functionality as is , i updated in my answer ...

Answer (score 1):

> How could I archive similar re-usability of the property code without relying on inheritance and the problems that come with it?

The alternative to using inheritance is either interfaces or composition. However, for properties specifically, you're a bit stuck.

- **Interfaces** cannot contain a default implementation the same way that a base class can. So while you can enforce that your classes use the correct "composed property structure", you can't make reusable methods available without implementing them in every class that implements the interface (*or can you? More after the break!*)
- **Composition** simply doesn't exist in C# in a way that you can add properties to a class on the fly (unless you are satisfied with a `Dictionary<string,string>`). There may be some contrived method to *technically* make it work, but it won't be a good approach.

---

**Interfaces + extension methods**.

Extension methods can be used here to replace the reusable logic that you'd find in an inherited base class.

**There is one drawback to this:** The properties that you wish to access inside the extension methods need to be part of the interface contract and publically accessible.
Other than this drawback, it ticks the box on every other requirement you have.

---

First, an inheritance-based example:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyComposedObject
{
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    public Property GetProperty(string name)
    {
        return this.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    }
}

public class Person : PropertyComposedObject
{

}
```

---

If we were to use an interface instead, we would lose access to benefits such as a shared `GetNode(string)` method. You could add it as part of the interface, but each implementing class would then be responsible for implementing that method (leading you to copy/paste the same methods all over the place).

An interface example without extension methods:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IPropertyComposedObject
{
    List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    Property GetProperty(string name);
}

public class Person : IPropertyComposedObject
{
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    public Property GetProperty(string name)
    {
        return this.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    }
}
```

---

But extension methods allows us to define the reusable method **once** but still access it from every class that implements the interface:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IPropertyComposedObject
{
    List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPropertyComposedObject
{
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public static class IPropertyComposedObjectExtensions
{
    public Property GetProperty(this IPropertyComposedObject obj, string name)
    {
        return obj.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! But I think I need to reread it a few more times, till I really understand if it solves my problem.

Comment: @RubenBohnet: It may be easiest to simply try it out; which is why I gave the three examples (inheritance, interface, interface+extensions). Copy/paste the code (include your `Node` class) and then try and do something like `var personAge = myPerson.GetNode("Age");` You'll see that it works in all three cases, but only the third example avoids **both** inheritance and copy/pasting the same method logic in every implementing class.

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you, after I tried it out in my project. Curious to see if it works with my wpf visualisation!

Comment: Dough! Now I got it ... So, this introduces the properties as a layer of child nodes, correct? Then (imho) this is quite similar to _only_ having structured nodes, right? Only that leaves won't have children that have children ...

Comment: @Fildor: I took the `Node` class to be _a single property_, thus using `List<Node>` as a list of properties. If OP's intention was to add a list of properties to the `Node` class; then I should rework my answer to use a `MyProperty` class instead of a `Node` class. But the rest of the answer is still the same. (Re-reading the question, I was indeed mistaken to assume that `Node` was the representation of a property. I'll update the answer.)

Comment: @RubenBohnet: Read the comment above. I'm going to fix the answer. It's mostly the same, but instead of referring to `Node`, I shoudl've been referring to a `MyProperty` class that still needs to be created.

Comment: @Flater Thanks for the extra effort! Could you include an example of how to access an property not defined in the current class.

Comment: @RubenBohnet: That very much depends on what you want to happen when you try to access a non-existing property. Throw an exception? Return `null`? Return a default value? _Create_ the requested property with a default value? Send an email to someone? Play a "bwaaap bwaaaaaap" sound file? The world's your oyster, you can make it do whatever you want it to do.

Comment: @Flater Intuitively I would say I need to dispatch over the type of node before anyway, so there should be no accesses to properties that are not set beforehand. If so, they can return a default value "" though.

Comment: You should avoid using extension methods, cause they reduces testablility. On the other hand storing property values in an object named Property is not a good practice, because you are loosing readablity and understanablity and there is no real interface or class definition. It's just a place to carry data.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat How does it lower testability? Also, while it does indeed deviate from C#'s usual way of doing things, [ECS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) is a well designed system. Whether you call them components or properties is a matter of naming. It cost additional overhead to check if a given entity has a given component, but it does free you from overly rigid types and inheritance.

Comment: @Flater Extension methods are static, there is no standard way to mock static members. Something that is not testable is not extendable and maintainable. I do not recommend microsoft fakes and shims, because they promote bad design.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat Can you actually backup that claim that extension methods are not testable?

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat: You could redesign the extension class to be an `IPropertyComposedObjectHandler` which works non-statically and therefore can be mocked easily; but you'd be creating bulkier code in regards to fetching properties as a consequence. The extension methods for properties would generally consist out of _utility methods_ (e.g. getting a property based on a name), and I wonder how relevant it is to mock those. If you mock them, all your business logic (which will rely on reading/writing properties) will start failing.

Comment: @Flater Setting up a property getter is very common in unit testing. That is very easy when we have a normal property (get,set). On the other hand there would be extended logic on changing property that is not relevant to a specific unit test, so extension methods would block or at least make unit testing less efficient. That's the way extension methods or any static methods affect testability, and as you said results in a bulkier code when refactored.

Comment: @Flater But type safty code is as important as testability. Property.Value is a string! Making Property class generic or the GetProperty method generic adds some value casting and the code would not be type safe anymore.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat: You're right that ECS compromises some other things such as type safety. However, the decision to use ECS takes precedence over your concerns. Observe the priorities here. Making a big decision (using ECS) is going to come with a range of benefits and drawbacks. We can only assume that OP (or their lead) have made an informed decision as to implementing ECS, and that its usage is justified.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to minimize code duplication:

```
interface INodeProperties
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

class NodeProperties : INodeProperties
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

interface INode
{
     INodeProperties NodeProps { get; set; }
}

class Node : INode
{
     public INodeProperties NodeProps { get; set; } = new NodeProperties();
}

interface IStructuredNode
{
      List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}

class StructuredNode: INode, IStructuredNode
{
     public INodeProperties NodeProps { get; set; } = new NodeProperties();
     public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Downside: One more "hop" to get to the actual Properties ... :(

Comment: I like the approach. I will at continue to think into that direction.

Comment: @RubenBohnet What just occurred to me: If your properties are all strings and you need your Nodes to really be flexible about them, how about just using a `Dictionary<string,string>`? But I guess you want to use binding, right?

Comment: Doesn't this just wrap the `List<Node>` in a `NodeProperties` class; while not really changing how the `List<Node>` works internally? This seems to only add a redundant layer. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, not the List<Node>. All the _other_ properties. I assumed OP really has a rather long list of common properties. So my goal was to minimize code duplication while adding the functionality of having children to a node.

Comment: @Fildor Since there is an wpf visualisation attached to it I would rather not change to much how the view-model hinted at in my question presents itself to the outside. If nothing else helps I will continue your line of thought though!

Comment: @Fildor That is correct. There are around 10 common properties.

Comment: I can not identify INodeProperties nor Node Properties. They are poorly designed. Classes should have both data and behavior. If those properties belong to Node then put then in Node not in a class carrying just data and you named that NodeProperties, look at the name and you find that out.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat You did not understand the concept, obviously. I wouldn't judge a design I don't grasp if I were you. Also _"Classes should have both data and behavior."_ - citation needed.

Comment: @Fildor It is not judging, here we are critisizing ideas. Here is the source: "basic idea of object-oriented design; which is to combine data and process together." --Martin Fowler (https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

Comment: _"They are poorly designed."_ That's a judgement. _Your_ judgement. And you seem to be mislead regarding the meaning of the words "should" and "basic idea".

Answer (score 0):

Have an INode interface, which encapsulates common properties.

This way you should have auto properties, then avoid putting logic in properties' getter and setter, because you can not reuse this logic.

Then repeating auto property definitions is not important and does not affect reusability.

If you need property change notification, it is better to use interceptor libraries such as [postsharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-conceptual).